# android mirroring imageresource in src of imagebutton

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I set the ImageResource of an ImageButton programmatically, while itself is created in xml:

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/id_of_image_button"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/id_of_other_image_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_of_image_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_of_image_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

in java I set the src (depends on other code...)

```
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.id_of_image_button);
    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.src_of_image_button);
```

How can I mirror the ImageResource (src only, NOT the background)? Is there any solution (in Java/XML) which doesn't blow up the simple code? ;)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you want to create a second image button with the same Image Resource ?

Comment: ah, sorry. No I've got one drawable which is shown on two imageButtons, but one has to show the resource mirrored.

Comment: You can do that with a matrix

Comment: Ok, now i understand ! You have two possible solutions: if the image is static , you can flip it with a image editor. The the image source can change, you need to apply a transformation like matrix which is very heavy on the device.

Comment: I tried `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();matrix.postRotate(180);ib.setImageMatrix(matrix);` after `ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.src_of_image_button);` - doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method to your code

```
private final static Bitmap makeImageMirror(final Bitmap bmp)
{
    final int width = bmp.getWidth();
    final int height = bmp.getHeight();

    // This will not scale but will flip on the X axis.
    final Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.preScale(-1, 1);

    // Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
    final Bitmap reflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, mtx, false);

    // Create a new Canvas with the bitmap.
    final Canvas cnv = new Canvas(reflection);

    // Draw the reflection Image.
    cnv.drawBitmap(reflection, 0, 0, null);

    //
    final Paint pnt = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in.
    pnt.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));

    // Draw a rectangle using the paint.
    cnv.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, pnt);

    return reflection;
}
```

Then, get your mirrored image like so:

```
    final ImageView imgMirror = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMirror);
    imgMirror.setImageBitmap
    (
        makeImageMirror
        (
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.head_prof)
        )
    );
```

Result:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

You can get the VERTICAL mirror by using this matrix: `mtx.preScale(1, -1);`
You can get the HORIZONTAL + VERTICAL mirror by using this matrix: `mtx.preScale(-1, -1);`

Comment: copy/paste and crashed down `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()` on `Bitmap.createBitmap(...`?

Comment: I fixed the errors. And added a demo picture of the result. The original image is the left head and the "mirrored" one is the one on the right.

Comment: I like you! Works fine :) And I reset the Bitmap via `ib.setImageBitmap(null);` thank you for your effort

Comment: Thank you, dear. Nice to be helpful. By the way, the original image was taken from Google using the images features and looking for profile - Just in case you liked the head and wanted to get it.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flip it in the code you can do something like this:

```
BitmapDrawable flip(BitmapDrawable d)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.preScale(-1, 1);
    Bitmap src = d.getBitmap();
    Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), m, false);
    dst.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return new BitmapDrawable(dst);
}
```

You can switch the `preScale` values if you want to mirror on the X axis.

Comment: First of all create a bitmap from your resource , something like `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_search);`  !  Next, you need to create a drawable from the bitmap you just created with `Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);` ! Now you have a DrawableBitmap of your resource and you can call the method i presented which will mirror you resource. Hope it works for you and sorry for the lack of good format :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Assuming you are going to mirror on Y axis

```
private void mirrorMatrix(){
       float[] mirrorY = {  -1, 0, 0, 
                       0, 1, 0,  
                       0, 0, 1    
                   };
       matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
       matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);    
   }
```

then get the mirrored bitmap and set it to the next `imageButton`.

```
private void drawMatrix()
{

  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY); 

  Bitmap mirrorBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
  ib.setImageBitmap(mirrorBitmap);
}
```

**Note:**
`mirrorY` with the `Matrix.postConcat()` generates a mirror image about Y axis.